# GetMapping returning error 405 in spring boot

Tags: api, spring-boot, http

I have a system that uses Spring Boot in the server side. I'm getting an error that I can't see what is happening here.

That's my controller with the following end point:

```
@GetMapping("/api/getAge")
public int getAge (@RequestParam("person") Person p) {
    return this.computeAge(p);
}
```

The method compute age returns (obviously) the person's age. The thing is:  when I use postman to this route, the method runs but I get a http error 405.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `@ResponseBody` annotation:

```
@GetMapping("/api/getAge")
@ResponseBody
public int getAge (@RequestParam("person") Person p) {
    return this.computeAge(p);
}
```